# Wrapping jQuery for each loop in <li>

Tags: jquery

Code I'm using is here: https://gist.github.com/783947

Wondering how I can wrap a list item around the avatar and link like so:

```
<li class="entry"><img src="gravatar.png"><a href="#">@twittername</a></li>
```

I've looked at .prepend and .append as well as .wrap but these do not seem to be able to grab multiple html elements, see them as a group and wrap an html element around them. (I could very well be wrong.)

I'll also admit that I'm not super familiar with jQuery sytax so this is probably a n00b question.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Wrote this out the long way, so you have a better idea of what's goin' on.

Edit: Yeah, I should probably include the "wrapping in an li" part, huh?

---

```
        var $img = $('<img />')
                .addClass('avatar')
                .attr('src', "http://wil.to/img/200x200"),

            $link = $('<a />')
                .attr('href', "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + entriesObject.Field17)
                .text("@" + entriesObject.Field17)
                .after($img);

            $('#people').append($link).wrapInner('<li />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the `<img>` and `<a>` you create into the variables `img` and `a`, and then:

```
$('<li class="entry">').append(img).append(a).appendTo('#people');
```

---

Within your code, this would look like:

```
var img, a; // declare the two variables you'll be using

if (entriesObject.Field3 != "") {
    // Save the <img> to a variable after creating it
    img = $("<img />", {
        class: "avatar",
        src: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + MD5(entriesObject.Field3)
    }); // Don't append yet
}

if (entriesObject.Field17 != "") {
    a = $("<a />", {
        href: "http://twitter.com/" + entriesObject.Field17,
        html: "<p>@" + entriesObject.Field17 + "</p>"
    });
}

// Append to list here
$('<li class="entry">').append(img).append(a).appendTo('#people');
```

Comment: Hi Box9 - could you show me what you mean in the context of my code that im using? https://gist.github.com/783947 - I Get a bit hung-up on syntax.

Comment: @nikibrown, I've added an update that shows what it would look like in your code. Changes are shown in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

expanding on your code and Box9's answer:

```
// Field3 is the email field on this particular form
var $li= $('<li class="entry">');//CRETAE NEW LIST ITEM
if (entriesObject.Field3 != "") {

    $("<img />", {class: "avatar",src: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + 
                                    MD5(entriesObject.Field3)}).appendTo($li);
}

// check if twitter name is not empty
if (entriesObject.Field17 != "") {
    $("<a />", {href: "http://twitter.com/" + entriesObject.Field17,
                html: "<p>@"+ entriesObject.Field17 + "</p>"}).appendTo($li);   
}
$li.$("#people") //APPEND to PEOPLE
```